# Logical Consequence intuitive meaning - First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The definition of Logical Consequence is

> A formula φ is a logical consequence of a formula ψ if every
>   interpretation that makes ψ true also makes φ true. In this case one
>   says that φ is logically implied by ψ.

Ok. That's nice. But im not able to understand its practical meaning. What's the intuition behind this definition ?

Comment: The intuition is: $\varphi$ *follows from* $\psi$. See [Logical consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/).

Answer (score 3):

This definition goes back to [Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/):

> "A deduction is speech (*logos*) in which, certain things having been supposed, something different from those supposed results of necessity because of their being so. (*Prior Analytics* I.2, 24b18–20)"

An *argument* is a "speech" where we have some *premises* and a *conclusion*.

When the conclusion "follows from" the premises (by logic alone) we say that the argument is (logically) *valid* and the conclusion is a [logical consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/) of the premises.

In every mathematical theory, every *theorem* proved from the *axioms* of the theory is a logical consequence of the axioms.

---

The key point is the elucidation of the concept of *following by logic alone*.

We can use the notion of *logical form*, abstracting from the specific vocabulary of the argument and considering an argument schema that is *topic neutral*.

This technique is as old as formal logic itself. See Aristotle, *Prior An*, 26a16-26a30:

> if $A$ belongs to no $B$ and $B$ to some $C$, it is necessary that $A$ does not belong to some $C$.

The modern approach uses formal languages, with the logical machinery modelled with *connectives, quantifiers* (the *logical constants*) and *variables*.

In this way, a logical schema is one involving only the logical constants and topic-neutral vocabulary.

A logically valid inference is an instance of a logical schema all of whose instances are truth-preserving.

The way to assess the validity is to consider all possible instances, i.e. every interpretation of the variables.

---

For more details, see e.g. Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2003), **Ch.3 Patterns of inference**.